# What is the best approach to pass objects to subfiles in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

For exmple i have code like this:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(port, host);

var Stash = require('./lib/stash');
var stash = new Stash(data);

stash.search()
```

The `search` method contains few [request](https://github.com/request/request)'s in which callbacks I need to save data to the `Redis`. What is the best way to pass `client` to that callbacks?

```
Stash.prototype.search = function(search) {
    var self = this;

    request(SEARCH_URL + '?' + querystring.stringify(this.params), function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Here i need REDIS
        }
    });
};
```

Through the `search` method as a parameter and then add to the callback? Basically I need to have `Redis` in more than one place so I need to do is something like static class in `PHP`. Is it possible or may in `NodeJS` there is some specific techniques?

Comment: I think you should have a Redis connection initiated at your config level. so something like `config.redis` would always be the same object not a copy or a new object each time.

Answer (score 2):

How about just keep all operation on redis in one separate file named `redisoperation.js`.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client;
exports.init = function init() {
    if (typeof client === 'undefined') {
        client = redis.createClient(port, host);
        client.on("ready", connectionEstablished);
        client.on("error", connectionError);
        client.on("end", connectionLost);
    }
}

exports.saveDataToRedis = function (data) {
    // save data to redis through client
}

exports.getDataFromRedis = function (key) {
    // get data from redis through client
}
```

App.js

```
// init the redis connection firstly
var rd = require('./redisoperation.js');
rd.init();

// other operation on redis through `rd.saveDataToRedis(d)` or `rd.getDataFromRedis(k)`
```

Also for other files which want to use `redis` related api, could require `redisoperation.js` as above, and invoke them.

---

Per [`require` doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

No multiple copies of `redisoperation.js` as your comment point out.

Comment: But in this way I will have more than one copy of the same object. In my case I will have 11 connections to the `Redis` as I have 11 different modules.

Comment: @user1564141, you means `require('./redisoperation.js');` could make multiple copy of that object? if so, the require just get this object from cache. `Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.` please refer to this [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: Good one, I didn’t know about it, but still when I call init each time it will execute the code in it ? Or I need to call init in the main file to initialize and the use set/get methods in sub files ?

Comment: @user1564141, Yes, when you can `init` in each file, it will be executed multiple time, you should only call it in the main js file once, normally named app.js. then you should use get/set method in other files.

Answer (score 1):

If your `search` function was defined in current module, there would be no better way to use client than to just define it as a variable at module's root level.

As it stands, best approach in my opinion would be to use `Promise`. Make it so that your search method returns a promise and then define a callback for that promise in the current module. It would look like this:

```
stash.search().then(function(results) {
  //saveStuff is the made-up function. Use your redis API here to save stuff. If your saving logic was inside the search function before, you were doing something wrong.
  client.saveStuff(results);
})
.except(function(err) {
  //This is the reject handler.
  console.log(err);
});
```

If you were to use ES6 promises, search method would look something like this:

```
function search() {
  //Resolve and reject are functions that mark promise as completed successfully or with error respectively. You can pass some data into them.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //This is your async search logic (using request module).
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //You may wanna transform response body somehow.
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You can read more info on ES6 promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: As I mentioned in search method is https://github.com/request/request in which callback I need to use `redis`, not in `search` it self.

Comment: This technique does not have anything to do with the modules that you use. Promises can be used to simplify work with pretty much anything asyncronous. I've shown you the most basic way you can use them in your code.

Comment: So basically when I call `resolve(body);` in the callback it would invoke `then` in my main file?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. It would also pass the data, you've given to resolve to  the 'then' handler.

Comment: You can also add error handling logic in the 'except' handler of the promise as shown above.